# How do i write else after all foreach passes

Tags: php, laravel

`$assignments` has many assignments and each assignment has a deadline. I have printed *assigmnet deadline reached* for each assignment if they crosses the deadline. But, i would like to print No *Notifications* if none have reached the deadline.

```
  @foreach($assignments as $assignment)
       @if($assignment->deadline<$now)
        <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" role="alert">
              <li> Assignment deadline reached for {{$assignment->assignment}}</li>
        </div>                    
       @endif       
   @endforeach
```

How can I acheive this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one. Using True and False in a variable.

```
@php  $deadline = false @endphp
@foreach($assignments as $assignment)
       @if($assignment->deadline<$now)
        @php  $deadline = true @endphp
        <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" role="alert">
              <li> Assignment deadline reached for {{$assignment->assignment}}</li>
        </div>                    
       @endif     
   @endforeach
       @if($deadline = false)
        <p>
        No Notifications
        </p>                    
       @endif
```

Comment: I don't see how this one works.. If the foreach never runs, $deadline is never set, causing an error. Also, you are giving your page all of the data and calculating in blade instead of using a controller to deliver only the necessary data.

Comment: @GoogleMac  Just add $deadline = false 

before foreach.

Answer (score 1):

Add a counter in for each to count any assignment is within deadline

```
<?php
$within_deadline = 0;
@foreach($assignments as $assignment)
   @if($assignment->deadline<$now)
    $within_deadline++;
    <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" role="alert">
          <li> Assignment deadline reached for {{$assignment->assignment}}</li>
    </div>            
   @endif       
@endforeach

// Display message if no within deadling
@if($within_deadline === 0)
  <div>No Notifications</div>
@endif
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can do what you are looking for within a Blade template. You would need to be able to set a variable that changes if a deadline has been reached, but this is discouraged to do in a view so there is no blade tag for it.

You would have to put this logic in your PHP code, then send to the view the variable, eg 'no_notifications'.

I would suggest putting the `@if($assignment->deadline<$now)` into the PHP code, and just sending the view an array of assignments that had reached the deadline. If the array is empty, return the output required to notify 'No  Notifications'

Answer (score 1):

Things tend to work best in MVC programming when you provide just enough data to work. I recommend only supplying the page with those assignments that are past deadline if that is all you plan on showing.

To do this, in your controller remove all assignments that are past due by comparing them to the current date/time (I can't see your controller so I can't give you much more than this). Pass only those overdue to the view and then use this blade code:

```
@if( isset($assignments[0]) )
    @foreach($assignments as $assignment)
        <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" role="alert">
            <li> Assignment deadline reached for {{$assignment->assignment}}</li>
        </div>                         
    @endforeach
@else
    // display 'No notifications'
@endif
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Another thought would be to actually ensure that you only select records that are `< $now`. I'm not sure how your controller looks but you could achieve that using `->where('time_field', '>=', Carbon::now())` (replace time_field with your field obviously).

After you have only the records you want to display you could do:

```
@if(!$assignments->count())
    <div><p>No Notifications</p></div>
@else
    @foreach($assignments as $assignment)
        <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" role="alert">
            <li> Assignment deadline reached for {{$assignment->assignment}}</li>
        </div>                         
    @endforeach
@endif
```

Remember that the database is your friend when building applications. Leave the heavy lifting on the database and it will make your code easier to write/maintain.